# Отследить нажатие двух клавишь одновременно JS

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

есть игрушка на js - ping-pong. Проблема в том, что одна клавиша прерывает нажатие другой клавиши и соответственно платформа останавливается. Как можно сделать так, чтобы отслеживалось нажатие 2х клавиш одновременно

Answer (score 0):

Первая ссылка в гугл https://learn.javascript.ru/task/check-sync-keydown
**Нужно создать несколько обработчиков события**